# How to get the (http) protocol version in puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

I am trying to get the HTTP version of a response I get using Puppeteer `1.19.0`. I hoped it was part of the response object but it was not.

Is there a way to retrieve the version like `h2` or `http/1.1`?

I did not find any pieces of information within the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get it with `evaluate` function:

```
await page.goto('https://google.com');
const httpVersion = await page.evaluate(() => performance.getEntries()[0].nextHopProtocol);
console.log('HTTP version: ', httpVersion);
```